# Show that $\log|\sin(z)|$ is the real part of a holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

$D$ is a connected, simply connected domain with $\sin(z)$ never zero on D. Show that $\log|\sin(z)|$ is the real part of a holomorphic function.

My question is: how to show $\sin(z)$ maps a simply connected set to a simply connected set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is: how to show $\sin(z)$ maps a simply connected set to a simply connected set?

It need not. If $D$ is for example the upper half plane, the line $\operatorname{Im} z = 1$ is mapped to an ellipse that winds around $0$. However, since $D$ is by assumption simply connected, and $\sin$ has no zeros in $D$, the logarithmic derivative

$$\cot z = \frac{\cos z}{\sin z}$$

has a primitive $h$ on $D$. $h'(z) = \cot z$ means that $e^{-h(z)}\sin z$ is constant, and by adding a suitable constant to $h$ you can achieve

$$\sin z = e^{h(z)}$$

on $D$. Then you have $\log \lvert\sin z\rvert = \operatorname{Re} h(z)$.

Comment: So where is the branch cut?

Comment: There is no branch cut. Although the image $\sin (D)$ may wind around $0$, you can still have a logarithm of $\sin$ on $D$. It's like $e^z$ on $\mathbb{C}$, the image of that also winds around $0$, but a logarithm of $e^z$ exists ($z \mapsto z - 2\pi i$ is one). The thing is that in a simply connected domain, all paths from one point to another are equivalent (homotopic), so whenever you have a closed path, if you follow a logarithm of $f(z)$, where $f$ has no zeros on $D$, you get back to the value you started with.

Answer (score 0):

Try $$\log(sin(z)).$$ Recall that $\log(re^{i\theta}):=\log(|r|)+i(\theta+2\pi k)$.

Comment: You need to prove the domain of $sin(z)$ is simply connected first, so you can give it a branch cut.

Comment: Yes. I overlooked that that was your actual question.